# How to response ajax search output to view ~laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I am trying to send json response on my ajax into my view on my laraveL.
But i can't get any good codes for it, exam

```
public function viewMasakanAjax(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {

        $alberMasakan = Masakan::where('alber_nama_masakan','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();

        return response()->json($alberMasakan)->view('kasir/ajax-menu');
    }
}
```

When i am try that code, it doesn't work.

also this is my view

```
@foreach($alberMasakan as $alberData)
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="card card-figure">
        <figure class="figure">
            <div class="figure-img">
                <figure class="figure">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('kasir/images/seafood.jpg') }}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                        <h6 class="figure-title"> Simple figure </h6>
                        <p class="text-muted mb-0"> Give some text description </p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

here my ajax code

```
<script>

$('#cariData').on('keyup',function(){
    $value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({   
        type : 'get',
        url : '{{route('admin.ajax')}}',
        data:{'search':$value},
        success:function(data){
            $('.ajax').html(data);
            if ($value == '') {
                $('.isi').remove();
            }
        }
    });
})

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });

</script>
```

my route on web.php

```
Route::get('/cari', 'KasirRestoran\DetailOrderController@viewMasakanAjax')->name('admin.ajax');
```

Comment: From code `$('.ajax').html(data)`, I assume you expect the `/cari` API to return HTML instead of JSON. In that case, you may want to use this instead in your controller: `return view('kasir/ajax-menu', $alberMasakan);`

Comment: If something doesn't work, you should post details of exactly what's not working, any errors, etc. "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us much about what's really happening.

Comment: well, i think my code its not work cause `$('.ajax').html(data);` that code is replacing a json data into HTML

Comment: @DaveS nothing message erros was appear, just my `kasir/ajax-menu` its dont work properly. Maybe cause this issue `$('.ajax').html(data)`

Comment: Then you don't want JSON data, you want HTML. I'll edit and undelete my answer to reflect this.

Comment: nope, its MVC, sure i want JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return *either* `$response->json()` **or** `view()`, but not both together.

Your javascript is expecting to see HTML content, but you're feeding it JSON data. To pass data to a view, use something like this:

```php
public function viewMasakanAjax(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $alberMasakan = Masakan::where('alber_nama_masakan','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();

        // Pass $alberMasakan as data along to the view
        // Same as view('kasir/ajax-menu')->with($alberMasakan)
        return view('kasir/ajax-menu', $alberMasakan);
    }
}
```

Comment: it still, doens't work `return view('kasir/ajax-menu', $alberMasakan);`

Comment: i got error on my console `GET http://localhost/UjikomAlber/public/admin/cari?search=sea 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
public function viewMasakanAjax(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {

        $alberMasakan = Masakan::where('alber_nama_masakan','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();

        return response()->json($alberMasakan);
    }
}
```

Comment: how i send $alberMasakan into my view ?

Comment: You should set html through javascript in your ajax response.